# Introduce new data source in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am new to Terraform and have been trying to understand the constructs of the same. Let's say i have a service which exposes REST API's and i want to call those REST API's as part of my terraform script, what are the steps i need to take ?

My understanding is that i need to write a custom provider but i am unable to connect the dot's on how to add new data source type for the new provider.

Also, assuming that we do have the required provider, whats the protocol that would be used for communicating with my service ? Is it HTTP/s ?

One more point to note is that my service currently is used for configuring storage in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of terraform ( > 0.9 I believe) support [external data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/external/data_source.html). You don't have to create a custom provider. You can call any arbitrary shell or python script that return values that you can use as data.

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = ["python", "${path.module}/example-data-source.py"]

  query = {
    # arbitrary map from strings to strings, passed
    # to the external program as the data query.
    id = "abc123"
  }
}
```

In your case you could use a simple curl in a bash script to call your endpoint and return data to terraform as a map of strings.

Do note the warnings a the top of that page.

Comment: This would mean that we could always have some script external doing all the heavy lifting while we just call it in terraform right ?

Comment: for the "calling rest api to fetch some arbitrary data" part, yes.

Answer (score -1):

This is considerably more difficult then it appears; it is impossible to debug the interaction between what terraform is sending to my script and what the script is expecting. It just fails to parse the arguments and refuses to provide me any feedback as to what is getting into the program

Comment: DV because this doesn't seem to be a helpful answer. If you are trying to address OP's problem, please make it more clear.

Comment: Looks like this is meant to be a comment on my answer above, a valid one at that. I guess the user doesn't have sufficient rep to post it as a comment.